# How do I unbind another jQuery function on .click()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this script that run to fix my menu bar to the browser on scroll. Nothing really needs to change here (works as it should). However, you may need it...

```
var div = $('#wizMenuWrap');
var editor = $('#main_wrapper');
var start = $(div).offset().top;

$(function fixedPackage(){   
    $.event.add(window, "scroll", function() {
        var p = $(window).scrollTop();
        $(div).css('position',((p)>start) ? 'fixed' : 'static');
        $(div).css('top',((p)>start) ? '0px' : '');

        //Adds TOP margin to #main_wrapper (required)
        $(editor).css('position',((p)>start) ? 'relative' : 'static');
        $(editor).css('top',((p)>start) ? '88px' : '');
    }); 
});
```

Now for the issue at hand. I have another script function that calls a modal pop-up (which again works as it should). However, it's not slick from a UI perspective when I scroll the page when the modals open. So I want to disable the script above when the modal script below is called. In other words, when I click to open the modal pop-up, the script above shouldn't work.

```
$(function () {

var setUp = $('.setupButton');

// SHOWS SPECIFIED VIEW

$(setUp).click(function () {        
    $('#setupPanel').modal('show');
    //PREVENTS PACKAGE SELECT FIXED POSITION ON SCROLL
    $(setUp).unbind('click',fixedPackage);
});

})
```

As you can see above, I tried to unbind the scroll function (the first code snippet), but this is not correct.

These two scripts are in two separate js libraries.

Comment: As far as I know, you can only use `unbind` if you used `bind` previously.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/off/
That's with JQuery version 1.7+ though I think

Comment: If this is your own code that you control, please don't use the jQuery internals such as `$.event.add`. The way to do it using the public api is `$(window).bind("scroll", function(){})`

Comment: See my answer for the docs -- `bind` is the correct way to add events to an element.

Comment: @Shenaniganz, _The off() method removes event handlers that were attached with .on()_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly disagree that you ought to be binding and unbinding the event. There's no need! A little logic in your scroll event to check to see if the modal is open should take care of the issue:

```
$(function fixedPackage(){   
    $(window).bind("scroll", function() {

        // if the modal is displayed, do nothing
        if ($('#setupPanel').is(':visible'))
            return;

        // -- existing code here --
    }); 
});
```

This way, if the modal element is visible, the code simply stops where it is. Once you hide the element, the code will continue to work as before without having to manage the state of event in some other script... confusing!

Also, as mentioned in some other comments, don't use `$.event.add`, use the public API method `bind`

**Documentation**

- jQuery `is` - http://api.jquery.com/is/
- jQuery `visible` selector - http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/
- jQuery `bind` - http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Answer (score 1):

When you store a jquery object into a var you can call functions directly:

```
var setUp = $('.setupButton');
var div = $('#wizMenuWrap');
var editor = $('#main_wrapper');

setUp.click(...);
seTup.unbind(...);

editor.css(...);

div.css(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
  $(setUp).unbind('click').die('click')
```

Answer (score 0):

all you need to do is change your script to:

```
$(function () {

var setUp = $('.setupButton');

// SHOWS SPECIFIED VIEW

$(setUp).bind('click',function () {        
    $('#setupPanel').modal('show');
    //PREVENTS PACKAGE SELECT FIXED POSITION ON SCROLL
    $(setUp).unbind('click');
});

})
```

As explained in the jQuery Docs, `Event handlers attached with .bind() can be removed with .unbind()` . For more information about bind and unbind:

[.bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)

[.unbind()](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)

Comment: Absolutely and thanks! However, I'm looking to unbind the first block of code in my post. So when the setUp.click function is called the OTHER function (i.e. $(function fixedPackage()) no longer works.